# how to get images to print in loop

Tags: php

This is probably a very simple solution but I am new to PHP I have been searching google to find out how to get it to work to no avail. Here is my problem I want to be able to use the `glob` function along with `extract(pathinfo)` to find all images in a folder and print them into an html page. I can only get one image to print to the screen I figured it would print them in order it finds the files. Here is my code:

```
<?php 
$images = glob('*.{png,jpg,jpeg}', GLOB_BRACE);

foreach($images as $img) {
    extract(pathinfo($img));
    $thumb_name = "$filename.$extension";       
    //$thumb_name = $info['filename'] . '.' . $info['extension'];
    echo $thumb_name . "\n";
}
?>
```

And finally the html file:

```
<?php include 'index.php' ?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php echo "<img src=\"$thumb_name\" title=\"bar\" alt=\"foo\" />"; ?>
<?php echo "<img src=\"$thumb_name\" title=\"bar\" alt=\"foo\" />"; ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The loop works as expected. Are you running the script in the right folder?

Comment: You name your script `index.php` but it is included in another file, which is strange. It is much stranger when you actually include the script in `index.html`.

Comment: It was just how it worked out for naming them just to test things. The top code belongs to a file named index.php the one with the HTML code is index1.php I know the naming is odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**not actual working code, but just for u to get an idea**

Put the echo img inside the for loop

```
     $images = glob('*.{png,jpg,jpeg}', GLOB_BRACE);
     foreach($images as $img){
        extract(pathinfo($img))
      $thumb_name = "$filename.$extension";       
      echo     '<img src=\'.$thumb_name\.' title=\bar\ alt=\foo\ />';
           }
```